# How to cast a type when referencing the assembly

Tags: c#, casting

**Given**

An extension method to convert a type via casting.

```
    public static dynamic SwitchType(this dynamic ppo, 
        string classname, Action<dynamic> callback)
    {
        Type obj= Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(p => p.Name == classname)
            .First();
        var converted =(obj)ppo; <-- Error Here
        callback(converted);
    }
```

**Problem**

Compiler tells me it cannot find obj, so cast won't work.

Maybe I'm making this too complicated, but the ppo being passed in is a runtime object that I want to convert to a specific type of that same runtime object that  was created earlier and contains specific static field text I need.

I've already validated the return of obj in other code so that part is working.

**Further Information**

We are parsing approximately 11 different tables in a web page all using the same class name. I want to write all the assertions in one place one time for all 11 rows.  Each row has different content in it thus I have to have the instance of the saved class from when we created it, but all I have at runtime is the class name.  Each time we call TestEditorFields we have a different page object with the same structure just different property values.

```
 private void TestEditorFields(dynamic ppo)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(ppo.ActualHeaderText == ppo.ExpectedHeaderText, "UTSC1160-The actual header text was not as expected");
            Assert.IsTrue(ppo.ActualInputText == ppo.ExpectedInputText, "UTSC1170-The actual inputs text was not as expected");
            Assert.IsTrue(ppo.ActualLabelText == ppo.ExpectedLabelText, "UTSC1180-The actual labels text was not as expected");
            Assert.IsTrue(ppo.ActualRowHTML == ppo.ExpectedRowHTML, "UTSC1190-The HTML of the content rows was not as expected");
            Assert.IsTrue(ppo.ActualSelectedText == ppo.ExpectedSelectedText, "UTSC1200-The Selected Options are not as expected");
            Assert.IsTrue(ppo.ActualWarningText == ppo.ExpectedWarningText, "UTSC1210-The actual warning text is not as expected");
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you just return 'object'? What is your original problem?

Comment: We are automating test using Page Objects which are created dynamically at very specific times in a web pages workflow.  When we create them we save them to a file with the name of the specific thing we were doing.  In our test we must automate the return to those same places (no problem) but then instantiate the specific class to do the assertions.  The only thing we have at run time is the name of the class.

Comment: Then you don't need a cast, but a [factory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like one of most powerful features of .NET is missed in a lot of questions: **expression trees**.

With expression trees you can generate an expression which can get compiled into a delegate to perform the desired conversion (*bye bye reflection*).

For example:

```
var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
var convertExpr = Expression.Convert(paramExpr, obj);
var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda(convertExpr, paramExpr);
var compiledExprDelegate = lambdaExpr.Compile();
```

Now you can call the delegate using `Delegate.DynamicInvoke`:

```
object conversionResult = compiledExprDelegate.DynamicInvoke(ppo);
```

Since you're working with DLR using `dynamic`, the above code should work in your scenario...

Comment: @john if you use this answer, could you provides us the final code?

Comment: @Kalten Well, it's the final code, I just ommitted your own code :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer  How would I pass in a parm to the CTOR of obj?

Comment: @JohnPeters You would need to build a *new expression*. This should be another Q&A...I won't be able to answer it in a comment :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an object instance to a Type that you don't know at compile time.

You need A base class or interface that the target type implement.
Or find a specific method by reflection on this object.

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);
methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parametersArray);
```

Comment: Ok I get that part.  I think I need to factor out all commonality to an interface and then ensure each class implements it.  That way at run time I can morph it.  right?

Comment: *You can't cast an object instance to a Type that you don't know at compile time* => And then .NET 3.x gave us expression trees!!